# Intergrating Redux into a React- Native app that uses react-navigation

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm in the process of developing a mobile application that will need to manage the state of the entire application. To solve this issue I decided to integrate redux into the Tech stack. When I attempt to connect my redux store to the application to access information contained in the store I get an error in my simulator that tells me I need to pass the Provider with a state property as a parent to the App component. 
I attempt to do this through my index.js file on the top level of my file system; Within the AppRegistry registerComponent method, wrapping the "appName" with the Provider with the store added as a prop, with no luck.
Any suggestions will be helpful.

https://github.com/Wheaties247/filcrum

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like you have setup redux in your project.

You should do something like this on your main component

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import AppReducer from './src/reducers';
import { AppNavigator, middleware } from './src/navigators/AppNavigator';

const store = createStore(AppReducer, applyMiddleware(middleware));

class ReduxExampleApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReduxExample', () => ReduxExampleApp);

export default ReduxExampleApp;
```

check react navigation docs for more information about redux integration
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html#docsNav